# How to pull Google OAuth user data and store it in Firebase Firestore using getRedirectResult method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication to authenticate users on my website through two methods: email/password and Google OAuth Sign-In.

Whenever a user registers through the email/password method, I have the following code to save the information they entered in a Cloud Firestore document:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            setDoc(doc(db,"accounts",user.uid), {
                user_id: user.uid,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                date_of_birth: dob,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                date_created: date
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            //pass
        };
```

However, when they sign in with Google (I am using the redirect method), I can't figure out how to do the same thing: I want to pull in user data from their Google account (in general, only their first and last names, date of birth, and their Gmail address). I have gone through the docs for the getRedirectResult() method, but I am unsure how to proceed.

I need help with some basic code to just pull in this data after they register.

Any help is appreciated, as I have spent the last two days tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: @DougStevenson if I do want to use onAuthStateChanged(), where in the code would I need to put it to make it is executed after the redirect is resolved?

Comment: In the code of the page that gets redirected to?

Comment: The problem with that is the page redirects to a dashboard of sorts. Putting that code for creating that document there would conflict with the email/password users, who would have THEIR documents updated every time they open the page.

Comment: There is no way to get additional information from the OAuth provider in `onAuthStateChanged`. You will have to get that information in the `signInWith...` completion handler, and then cache it until you need it.

Comment: On second thought, this might be the way to go forward, in fact. I can perform a simple check to see if the document exists before creating it - so I won't have the conflict I mentioned above. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how would I go about with that then?

Comment: Did you already sign in with Google? If so, you get a result from *that* sign in (so before you call Firebase) that has the values for the scopes that you asked for in step 2 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get additional information from the OAuth provider in `onAuthStateChanged`.

You will have to get that information after you signed in with the provider. so before you call Firebase. The result from the provider has the values for the scopes that you asked for in step 2 here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#handle_the_sign-in_flow_with_the_firebase_sdk